# How to use print() command and make the shape of a numpy array consistent, during integration using scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I tried examining how spicy.integrate.ode works. The code below is simple code to do this.

```
def func(t, z, p):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    print('x :', x)
    print('x.shape :', x.shape)
    print('y :', y)
    print('y.shape :', y.shape)
    return [x*0, y*0]

t_ini = 0
t_fin = 1
x_ini = np.array([[2, 2]])
y_ini = np.array([[2, 2]])

solver = ode(func)
solver.set_integrator('dopri5')
solver.set_initial_value([x_ini, y_ini], t_ini)
solver.set_f_params([0])
solver.integrate(t_fin)
x_fin, y_fin = solver.y
print('x_fin :', x_fin)
print('y_fin :', y_fin)
```

However,

```
print('x :', x)
print('x.shape :', x.shape)
print('y :', y)
print('y.shape :', y.shape)
return [x*0, y*0]
```

didn't work. The result of the code was

```
x_fin : [[2. 2.]]
y_fin : [[2. 2.]]
```

.

Interestingly, when I changed `x_ini` and `y_ini` into

```
x_ini = np.array([[2]])
y_ini = np.array([[2]])
```

, the `print()` command worked and the result of the code was the repetition of

```
x : 2.0
x.shape : ()
y : 2.0
y.shape : ()
```

with the two lines after the repetition which are

```
x_fin : [[2.]]
y_fin : [[2.]]
```

.
It was strange that even if I put `x_ini` and `y_ini` having (1, 1) shape, both `print(x.shape)` and `print(y.shape)` showed ().

So the questions are:

1. Why the `print()` didn't worked for `x_ini = y_ini = np.array([[2, 2]])` and what I should to to make them work?
2. Why the shape of the numpy arrays which are `x` and `y` became () instead of (1, 1).
3. How to make the shape of the numpy arrays which are x and y be (1, 1) during the integration using scipy. What should I do if the shape of both `x_ini` and `y_ini` is (2, 2) and I want to make the shape consistent during the integration using scipy.

Is there any guys who know about these?

Answer (score 0):

I get a warning when using your initial value array:

```
In [9]: x_ini = np.array([[2, 2]])
   ...: y_ini = np.array([[2, 2]])
In [10]: solver.set_initial_value([x_ini, y_ini], 0)
Out[10]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab8953d60>
In [11]: solver.integrate(.1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:1181: UserWarning: dopri5: input is not consistent
  warnings.warn('{:s}: {:s}'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
Out[11]: 
array([[[2., 2.]],

       [[2., 2.]]])
```

The output is the same as the input

```
In [12]: np.array([x_ini, y_ini])
Out[12]: 
array([[[2, 2]],

       [[2, 2]]])
```

With

```
x_ini = np.array([[2]])
y_ini = np.array([[2]])
```

The initial value is a (2,1,1) array

```
In [18]: np.array([x_ini, y_ini])
Out[18]: 
array([[[2]],

       [[2]]])
```

That does run, but the values passed to your function are 0d arrays

```
x : 2.0
x.shape : ()
y : 2.0
y.shape : ()
```

===

Let's simplify the `func`:

```
In [20]: def func(t, z, p):
    ...:     print(type(z), z.shape, z)
    ...:     return z*0
    ...: 
In [21]: solver = ode(func)
    ...: solver.set_integrator('dopri5')
Out[21]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab6debe50>
In [22]: solver.set_f_params([0])
Out[22]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab6debe50>
In [23]: solver.set_initial_value([1,2], 0)
Out[23]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab6debe50>
In [24]: solver.integrate(.1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (2,) [1. 2.]
...
```

If I change the initial value to a (2,1,1), `func` gets the same inputs:

```
In [27]: solver.set_initial_value([[[1]],[[2]]], 0)
Out[27]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab6debe50>
In [28]: solver.integrate(.1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (2,) [1. 2.]
```

Change the input to a 3 element array:

```
In [31]: solver.set_initial_value([1,2,3], 0)
Out[31]: <scipy.integrate._ode.ode at 0x7f1ab6debe50>
In [32]: solver.integrate(.1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (3,) [1. 2. 3.]
```

From the docs:

```
f : callable ``f(t, y, *f_args)``
    Right-hand side of the differential equation. t is a scalar,
    ``y.shape == (n,)``.
    ``f_args`` is set by calling ``set_f_params(*args)``.
    `f` should return a scalar, array or list (not a tuple).
```

`f` returns `dy/dt`.  The `y` will be a 1d array, and it's supposed to return a like size array.  Note the `y.shape` requirement.

The `y` that `ode` passes to the function is derived from the initial value array.  A (2,1,1) input is flattened to (2,).  A (2,1,2) produces the warning.